# I have written two separate files, one containing classes and the other calling them but calling one makes object of all. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

separate.py

```
    class foo():
       print 'a bunch of time consuming work'

    class tryme():
       print 'try me'*
```

main.py

```
from separate import *

foo()
```

It however printed both:

```
a bunch of time consuming work
try me
```

Comment: Just a tip: You should use print like a function (print("...") ) to prepare for python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `from separate import *`
you execute the print command !
If you want to just make an instance do something like :

```
class foo():
  def my_print(self):
    print 'a bunch of time consuming work'
```

and call my print from main !

```
f = foo()
f.my_print
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write an init for your classes then it wont happen anymore!

```
class foo():
  def __init__(self):
    print('a bunch of time consuming work')

class tryme():
  def __init__(self):
    print ('try me')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because commands in the scope of the class are statically defined, when importing a module it also initiate the static fields when binding everything.
@Tino A gave a nice solution for you, but if you want to read some more material regarding **imports** in python try [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).